# How to create an NFC authentication with Raspberry Pi and card reader

Tags: authentication, nfc, raspberry-pi3

I'm kind of new with NFC and Raspberry Pi and I'm trying to create an authentication system for a PC using Pi with an ACR122U USB NFC Tag Reader. I was wondering if there's a way I can use NFC tag as authentication tool, so when the tag is tapped, it opens a url, connects to a remote database and checks if that is the original Tag and returns true or false. I'm kind of lost how to connect the tag to a remote database.

Answer (score 0):

You can use two approaches:
* Use two-way authentication between a smart card (e.g. NXP MIFARE Plus, NXP MIFARE DESFire) and the remote server. This is not possible using a NDEF message, but requires sending APDUs to the card.
* Use NTAG 413, which generates a CMAC within a NDEF message every time you tap it.
This CMAC can be verified by the backend.